# The Difference between "behalten", "beibehalten", "halten", "festhalten"

Tags: meaning

könnt ihr bitte mir den Unterschied zwischen "behalten", "beibehalten", "halten", "festhalten" erklären ?

Comment: Look it up in a dictionary. If you then still have questions, specify them more detailed. Explain why your research was not sufficient.

Comment: I think it is a good question, because the english translations can be very similar, but the question is not asked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **behalten**
>   Example: "Können wir bitte den Welpen behalten?" - "Could we please **keep** the puppy?"

It means to *keep* something, an object or e.g. an animal.

> **beibehalten** 
>   Example: "Die Aufstellung hat sich bewährt, wir sollten sie beibehalten." -  "The line-up worked out we should **keep** it."

Because the line-up is not a real thing/object you rather use beibehalten. 
It is rather used in context of abstract things, like a line-up.

> **festhalten** 
>   Example: "Der Boden rutschig, halt dich fest!" - "The floor is slippery, take a hold!"

It means to hold something physically. But you can use it in an abstract context, too. E.g. to preserve something e.g. an idea: "Die Idee sollten wir festhalten." - "We should keep this idea (in mind)" or even "We should write down this idea"

> **halten**

This word is very broad. It depends very on the context. E.g. To hold an object or to stop. But you can also say: Was hälst du von dem Mann?" - "What is your opinion about this men?"

Bottom line: these words are very broad and very context sensitive. But they have distinct meanings. Beibehalten can be replaced with behalten, when speaking colloquially.